# unable to read fileupload1.filename when placed in UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I have a form where users upload their picture to the registration form.. everything worked fine until i added an updatepanel and an Image control.

I placed an update panel, inside it i place a table with Fileupload control and an image control. once the button is clicked the image is uploaded to the images folder and the preview is displayed in image control.

Before making the modification it worked fine.. but now im unable to read the FileUpload1.Filename .. below is the code

Reg.aspx

```
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>

    <table> <tr>
<td>
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
                            <asp:Button ID="btnUpload1" runat="server" onclick="btnUpload1_Click" 
                                Text="Upload"  />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<Td>
 <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Width="147px" /></td></tr>
</table>
```

Reg.aspx.cs

```
protected void btnUpload1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = FileUpload1.FileName;


    try
     {
         var folder = Server.MapPath("~/UploadImages/");



         if (!Directory.Exists(folder))
         {
             Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
             Label1.Text = Label1.Text + " Directory  Created <br>";

         }
             var picUrl = Server.MapPath("~/UploadImages/"+   FileUpload1.FileName.ToString());
             if (CheckFileName(picUrl) == true)
             {
                 FileUpload1.SaveAs(picUrl);
                 Image1.ImageUrl = picUrl.ToString();
                 Label1.Text = Label1.Text + "Image Uploaded";
             }
             else
                 Label1.Text = Label1.Text +"File already exists";


    }
    catch (IOException ioex)
            {
            Console.WriteLine(ioex.Message);
            }


}

   private bool CheckFileName(string picUrl) {

    if (File.Exists(picUrl))
        return false;
    return (true);

}
```

Now im not able to read the filename from fileupload1 control..

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add **Postback Trigger** in your update panel. Have a look at below code sample

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updatePanel1">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="fileUploader"/>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="buttonSubmit" OnClick="buttonSubmit_OnClick" Text="Submit"/>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="buttonSubmit"/>
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**ASPX.cs**

```
protected void buttonSubmit_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var fileName = this.fileUploader.FileName;
}
```

Comment: the answer worked for me.. :) if i have 4 more buttons.. with same functionality. do i have to create that many triggers?
<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" />
<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="Button2" />
<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="Button3" />
<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="Button4" />
</triggers>

Comment: If you require postback triggers for those button then you should add it. Don't forget to mark it as an answer.

Comment: One more issues in the same thing .. i placed an Image control but its not displaying the preview after the button is clicked.. do i need to modify anythign for it..? its in the same code as above

Comment: use  this :   `Image1.ImageUrl = "~/UploadImages/" + FileUpload1.FileName.ToString();`

Comment: once again a big thnx for the answer.. but may i know why did'nt it work when in used "picUrl.ToString();" 
i tried tracing everything went fine even with this but the image never display..